# word 2013 figures not referencing numbered heading correctly

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a large document with many tables, images, and references (using endnote), and everything was working out fine. As the document grew I decided to add Numbering to the captions and this is where everything has gone wrong.

When I go to add a caption it tells me that it will be Figure 4.1 (as in the first figure in Chapter 4) but after I type in the Caption and click OK, the caption doesn't read *Figure 4.1 This is a great car*, it reads *Figure 0.1 This is a great car*. If I change the number to Heading 2 It would be *Figure 4.1.1 This is a great car*, and it reads *Figure 4.1.1 This is a great car*.

I cant see why it is doing this! I changed my Heading 1 to have Chapter preceding the number, but I hope this isn't causing the issue.

The Field Code for this is:

```
Figure {STYLEREF 1\s}.{SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 1}
```

Any help on getting this sorted out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using change tracking can sometimes cause this type of failure.

Comment: As in tracking changes? Do you know how to rectify the issue?

Comment: Yes, track changes can cause this problem. AFAIK the only way to rectify is to accept/reject all the changes. You could make a copy of your .doc and do that, just to verify that that is the problem (or at least, part of it). The field codes you quote are standard, and there's no reason to believe that the "1" does not work - AFAIK it is partly there to aid internationalisation (because the Heading level styles are called different things in different locales).

Comment: I just accepted all the changes, and removed any of my comments. It still did not work :( I consider this to be a serious problem as I would expect that most documents that people write that need to use numbered figures would be documents that have comments through them.

Comment: SO it's not that, then. Can you spell out what you are doing here: "I changed my Heading 1 to have Chapter preceding the number" ?

Comment: Instead of just having 1 as the title of heading so "1 Introduction" I have "Chapter 1 Introduction". So I have Chapter proceeding the auto-numbering of a Heading 1 number.

Comment: OK, so as long as the Chapter is inserted using the numbering dialog (and I don't know how else you can do it) that does not appear to make any difference. But do you find that if you modify the numbering to omit the "Chapter", it works again? The other possibiities that spring to mind are (a) the obvious one where you actually have a Heading 1 style paragraph somewhere between the chapter heading and the caption, but with no caption (e.g. an empty paragraph) and (b) perhaps some obscure problem to do with linked styles - haven't even tried looking at that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Despite some mentions in the documentation that you can reference styles like you did, just by number, I was suspicious of that.

I was able to make it work (I have Word 2007) like this:

`Figure {STYLEREF "Heading 1" \s}.{SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s "Heading 1"}`

Don't forget to `update fields` to see the results.

Comment: Hi pgr, I had tried that in the past when the issue first arose. The part that is really frustrating is the fact that when I first add the caption,it is displayed correctly in the popup window, but when it adds it to the document it is incorrect.

Comment: But are you saying that entering the fields exactly as I gave doesn't work? Because I tried what you gave me, and had exactly the same problem as you; but the changed version worked well for me.

Comment: Yep. I just tried it again to confirm, and still giving me Figure 0.1, and I did update the fields.

Comment: My hunch is that Word is still not getting the correct style name, because that's the same result you get if you used a non-existing style name. This could be because of some name difference, like "Heading1" without a space, or a different language "Título 1". I'm using Word 2007 in English, maybe you have some difference in your version of Word?

Comment: I am using an English version of word 2013.

Comment: Maybe your styles are named differently. Perhaps you could attach a link to a document with the problem. Just remove 99% of the text and make sure the problem still shows.